# Is there a way to host multiple Apple DocC Archives on one GitHub repository?

Tags: ios, macos, docc

I am trying to host multiple DocC archives on one GitHub repository. For example, let's have two frameworks in one repo. I want to be able to go to Apple Doc for each one of the frameworks but to have them hosted on that repo. Is that possible? I couldn't find the answer, except I do my hosting on my server.